# How to match with new RegExp exactly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
var str = "https://www.mysite.se/this-match?ba=11"
```

I need to match it exactly (between `/` and `?`), so only `this-match` matches, **not** `this-ma` or anything (shorter) that is contained in `this-match`.
I.e:

```
var myre = new RegExp('\/this-ma\?');
```

Still matches:

```
myre.exec(str)[0]
"/this-ma"
```

How can I avoid that a shorter string contained in `this-match` does give a match?

Comment: If you want `this-match` to be the only match then why are you supplying `this-ma` ?

Comment: @NeilLunn Because sometimes I have similar strings, which could be contained in `this-match`

Comment: Nope I don't get it. Exact match or Similar strings. Which one is it? Not really clear.

Comment: If I understand correct you are looking a way to get `this-match` using regex. If yes, you can check [this](https://regex101.com/r/WbSMsE/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of your regex is wrong. You'd think that `\?` would match literal `?` character, instead of being non-greedy modifier. Not true. Quite the opposite, in fact.

```
var myre = new RegExp('\/this-ma\?');
> /\/this-ma?/
```

The backslash here works within the string literal, and outputs single `?` to regex, which becomes non-greedy modifier. Use the regex literal.

```
var myre = /\/this-ma\?/
```

Comment: you can also use also use a double backslash when you define the pattern in a string.

Comment: @Sergio Tulensev Like this? `var myre = new RegExp('\/this-ma\\?');`

Comment: @user1665355: yes, if you're building regexes dynamically. If it's static, you should prefer regex literals

Comment: yes or `new RegExp('/this-ma\\?')`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks! It works.